# Getting closed caption data files from YouTube V3 API (in Delphi)

Tags: api, rest, delphi, youtube

When you upload a video to YouTube, it automatically transcribes it and creates three different CC (closed-caption) files. They can be downloaded via the YT Creator Studio. I want to write a small Delphi app that does that via the YT API and does some stuff with the CC file.

I've found some code that lets you upload and play videos, but nothing that accesses things like the CC data via API. One source says YT charges for some of their API, and other info that says that's not the case. But I've seen nothing on the V3 API.

I'm curious if anybody can clarify this situation and has some example code for getting the CC data via the V3 API. A Delphi example would be most helpful.

Comment: I'm positive that you will get the most accurate answer from YouTube.

Comment: Try asking the question without relating it to delphi